# Only allow access from localhost to admin-cli client with Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

We have never setup an admin account for the master realm, afaik. On first login we created other users with admin access, but never setup a password for the master realm admin.

Reasoning was that every admin user must have 2FA enabled.

I want to introduce infrastructure as code to our setup and want to use the tool `keycloak-config-cli` which only makes sense if it can access the master realm as an admin user.

Now setting up an admin user again would actually be okay if for example the admin-cli could only be used from localhost.

Is there a way to limit client access in this way? Most things I found on the topic will require a custom implementation it seems.